# What do I return?

Tags: java

I need to return numbers from a file, and currently I am returning the number of inputs vs the actual numbers that need to be printed out.

```
public static double readFile() throws IOException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("floats.txt"));
    int numOfInputs = input.nextInt();

    double[] array = new double[numOfInputs];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i]=input.nextDouble(); 
    }
    return numOfInputs;
}
```

My main goes as follows;

```
double file = readFile();
System.out.println(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the signature of the method to return a `double` array and return the `array`, because all the input read from the user goes into the `array` and that is what you want to return back to your method.

```
public static double[] readFile() {
    ...
    return array;
}
```

And in the calling method, retrieve the `double` array.

```
double[] file = readFile();
for(double d : file) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: So I did this, and now I have the error class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Where exactly do you have that error? Are you implementing an interface? In that case you need to method signature in the interface too.

Comment: Its occurring in the whole program, for each line. literally. lol

Comment: Do you have the closing brackets `}` for the `readFile()` method?

Comment: Yes, i checked all my brackets. Everything adds up, Im not sure why it won't compile

Comment: Unless I see the whole code, there is nothing else, I could point out to, which could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: You could edit your question and add it. Whole code in the sense, the class where the `readFile()` and `main()` method exist.

Answer (score 1):

Change `public static double` to `public static double[]`. You need to return `array`. And, you need `double[] file = readFile();` and then `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(file));`

Answer (score 1):

You may try to to change

```
public static double
```

to

```
public static double[]
```

Something like this:

```
public static double[] readFile() {
    //code here
    return array;
}
```

Also change your Main like this:

```
double file = readFile();
System.out.println(file);
```

to this:

```
double[] file = readFile();
for(double d : file) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```